# AngularJS - Is this the right way to write a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I was trying to declare a directive, it is apparently right but when I load it in html nothing occurs.

This is the code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular
        .module('App');

    app.directive('directiveFunction', directiveFunction);

    function directiveFunction(){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div>Example</div>',
            controller: directiveController,
            controllerAs: 'example',
            bindToController: true,
            link: linkFunction
        }
    }

    linkFunction.$inject = ['$scope', 'elem', 'attrs', 'ctrl'];

    function linkFunction(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {}

    function directiveController() {
        var example = this;
    }

})();
```

I call this in html as `<directive-function></directive-function>` but it does nothing.

Comment: first your code works, second - dont use $inject on linkFunction - you can not inject here.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov It works but I don't see anything in the html, maybe the files are wrong located.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle for you.. you are doing all well, I think that you are using it like

https://jsbin.com/koporel/edit?html,js,output

```
<directiveFunction></directiveFunction>
```

No, use `-` where case changes, like

```
<directive-function></directive-function>
```

Comment: I use the `<directive-function></directive-function>` tags as well, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Angular automatically coverts camel case to the `-`

Comment: I suspect that what is wrong is that the files are wrong located.

Comment: Are you importing that file into your html page?